# Can Monit be configured to never unmonitor/timeout a service?

Tags: linux, monitoring, monit

Monit seems to give up restarting a service if it fails a few times, and unmonitors it. I can’t find anything in the documentation about the specifics of when or why.

My Monit config would be setup as follows:

```
set daemon 10
set logfile /var/log/monit.log
set statefile /var/lib/monit/monit.state
set alert foo@example.com not { nonexist, action, instance }
include /etc/monit/conf.d/*
```

And this is an example of the Monit ruleset I am using:

```
check process myservice
  with pidfile /var/run/myservice/myservice.pid
  start program = "/home/myservice/current/start-myservice.sh"
    as uid myservice and gid myservice
  stop program = "/home/myservice/current/stop-myservice.sh"
    as uid myservice and gid myservice
  mode active
```

In my environment, I want it to keep trying on its poll intervals indefinitely. Is there any way to configure monit to *never* stop monitoring a service, even if it doesn’t start up successfully?

Comment: Please post a sample of your monit config.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/1229828 -- I removed some mail server/alert stuff and the HTTP server configuration from monitrc.  The other file is an example of our service configuration.  Note the lack of "if x restarts then timeout" clause in it.

Comment: I've wondered about this myself. Sometimes I just kill something to test what monit does and monit just unmonitors it.

Answer (score 5):

I would simply use a cron job that would run `monit start servicename` at the desired intervals. Of course, you can use groups for a finer control.

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up doing, but I'm not too happy about it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same issue where despite restarting monit, it would refuse to monitor after the timeout. Finally figured out had to delete the monit state file (`/var/.monit.state`) and restart monit to make it monitor all programs again.

Answer (score 2):

After doing some digging, it turns out Monit stores system monitoring data in a “state” file. And this “state” file keeps track of what services are being monitored/unmonitored.

So while this is a bit “brute force”-ish, it definitely works. If a service becomes “unmonitored” due to something like a timeout, then just remove the Monit state file from the system like this:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/monit/state
```

And then restart Monit like this and all should be good:

```
sudo service monit restart
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your Monit code snippet, it looks like you have to modify or add cycle statements to your process stanza. See the [relevant documentation here](http://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#setting_an_error_reminder) and [here](http://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#service_tests).

It seems like you may want to set your service tests to execute every cycle with no timeout statement. Also look at your monit homepage at http://hostname:2812`. Check the page for the relevant service and look at` the "Existence" field. Your default should look like:

```
If doesn't exist 1 times within 1 cycle(s) then restart else if succeeded 1 times within 1 cycle(s) then alert
```

Comment: Looking at the monit page for the service, existence field is set to that.  But the rule just doesn't seem to be obeyed.  With a service that is designed to fail (ie, just a shell script that echoes out the date and does `exit 1`) it still unmonitors quickly.  If I use "monit monitor joe-test" it stops monitoring after one failure.  With "monit start joe-test" it gives up after 2 tries.

Comment: just take out the if 5 restarts within 5 cycles then timeout
then monit system will not unmonitor it.